# Google Apps Script to order columns by name when pulling from Firestore

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore

I am pulling data from a collection of documents in Firestore and displaying this data in a Google Sheet.

Each time I run the function to get this data, the columns appear in a random order each time.

I would like the columns to appear in a specific order, or in alphabetical order.

This function gets my data and appends it to the spreadsheet:

```
function importData() {
  const firestore = getFirestore();

  const allDocuments = firestore.getDocuments('Data').map(function(document) {
    return document.fields;
  });

  const first = allDocuments[0];
  const columns = Object.keys(first);

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ss = sheet.getActiveSheet();
  ss.clear();
  sheet.appendRow(columns);

  allDocuments.forEach(function(document) {
    const row = columns.map(function(column) {
      return document[column];
    });
    sheet.appendRow(row);
  });

  trimData();
  formatData();
}
```

The `trimData()` function removes any useless text and white spaces such as the the field type, e.g. stringValue.

The `formatData()` function sets an alternating color scheme and sets the cell values to appear on the left border of each cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You always want to put the values using the same order of the columns.

### Modification points:

- About your following issue,

  > Each time I run the function to get this data, the columns appear in a random order each time.

  - I thought that the reason of your issue is due to the line of `const columns = Object.keys(first);`. In this case, the order of keys might be changed every run. So I would like to propose the following modification.
- And, in your script, `appendRow` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost will become high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4) In this case, I would like to propose to use `setValues`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

#### From:

```
const first = allDocuments[0];
const columns = Object.keys(first);

const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const ss = sheet.getActiveSheet();
ss.clear();
sheet.appendRow(columns);

allDocuments.forEach(function(document) {
  const row = columns.map(function(column) {
    return document[column];
  });
  sheet.appendRow(row);
});
```

#### To:

```
const first = allDocuments[0];
const columns = Object.keys(first).sort();
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
sheet.clear();
const values = allDocuments.reduce(function(ar, document) {
  const row = columns.map(function(column) {
    return document[column];
  });
  ar.push(row);
  return ar;
}, [columns.slice()]);
sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

- By this modification, the order of keys is always sorted, and you can use always the same order.

  - But, if you add other fields, the order of keys is also changed. So please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Benchmark: Reading and Writing Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Answer (score 0):

If allDocuments is an array you can sort it:

```
allDocuments.sort();
```

There are other options available for sorting arrays as well, I use this site all the time:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp